# Xamarin Binding Android add [Activity] attribute to generated class

Tags: binding, xamarin.android

I've been trying to bind an android 3rd party library for Xamarin.
I succeeded but there's some Manifest Data I'd like to automatically include
when someone uses my xamarin binding.

For the  tag, I figured out I can add them in AssemblyInfo.cs of my binding project and that'll make them appear in the Manifest of the project including my binding.

Now I want to add a bunch of other stuff... 
Some , , , , some of them with intent-filters... but I can't figure out how!

From what I read, an  element is added to the Manifest when your class has the [Activity] attribute. But the generated .cs binding class doesn't automatically add this [Activity] attribute. Tried to find a way of adding it through MetaData.xml but there doesn't seem to be a way. Tried to add it by using the Additions folder of my binding project but can't seem to make it work. I can't even add a method to an existing bound class actually...

Some help would be welcome :)

Thanks,

Comment: How did you bind the android 3rd party library?

Comment: Can you create a `partial class` and add the attribute above the class?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay,

I found the solution to the problem and it's like Jon Douglas said...
The binding project generated classes are all partial so you can add a partial
class with the same namespace and same name to the "Additions" folder and just
add whatever you want to that class. Like an attribute [Activity] for example :)

Thanks!